# Operador NOT em python

Tags: python, operadores

Em java temos o operador not, podemos utiliza-lo assim:

```
if (!metodo()) {
    //código
}
```

Estou apenas conhecendo python agora, e estou com um probleminha:

tenho uma função que adiciona nomes em uma lista:

```
def adiciona_perfis():
    quantidade = 0 
    nome = raw_input("Digite seu nome ")
    nomes.append(nome)
    quantidade += 1
```

E outro que verifica a variável quantidade:

```
def tem_vaga(quantidade):
    if quantidade == 3:
        return False
    return True
```

Queria chamar a função tem_vaga() dentro da função adiciona_perfis. Mas usando o not, em Java por exemplo, poderia fazer assim:

```
if (!tem_vaga(quantidade)) {
    //Código
}
```

Como posso fazer isso em Python?

Comment: Naldson, se alguma das respostas ajudou a resolver a questão, marque-a como aceita clicando na seta abaixo da pontuação da resposta escolhida!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

É com [`not`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not)

Cria um arquivo `.py` com o código abaixo e roda.

```
def tem_vaga(quantidade):
    if quantidade == 3:
        return False
    return True


def adiciona_perfis():
    quantidade = 3
    if (not tem_vaga(quantidade)):
        print("oi")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    adiciona_perfis()
```

Comment: Obrigado, Ricardo!

Answer (score 6):

No Python também tem o operador [`not`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not):

```
def adiciona_perfis():
    quantidade = 0 
    nome = raw_input("Digite seu nome ")
    nomes.append(nome)
    quantidade += 1

    if not tem_vaga(quantidade):
      # Código...
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Naldson Disponha, só uma coisa, na função `tem_vaga`, você compara se `quantidade` é igual a *3*, por que não verifica se `quantidade` é *maior* ou igual a *3*? assim: `if quantidade >= 3:`.

Answer (score 3):

Só para complementar, uma função onde você faz apenas uma comparação e retorna apenas True ou False, pode ser simplificada dessa maneira:

```
def tem_vaga(quantidade):
    return quantidade == 3
```

No caso acima você vai utilizar o not na hora de chamar a função: `if not tem_vaga(4): (...)`

Ou, utilizando o operador not dentro da função:

```
def tem_vaga(quantidade):
    return not quantidade == 3
```

A propósito, acredito que você deveria estar fazendo a comparação de quantidade é menor ou igual a 3, ou seja: `quantidade <= 3`.

Answer (score 2):

No seu caso, você poderia usar o operador `not` ou então verificar usando o operador de comparação `==` chegando se é `False`.

```
if tem_vaga() == False:
      // Não tem vaga

if not tem_vaga():
   // não tem vaga
```